# Do I have two strings in my memory, when I assign a string literal to char array

Tags: c, string

This came up in another questions comment

> String literals have static storage duration (see standard 6.4.5/6). – Jean-Baptiste Yunès

And I didn't want to hijack the comment section for this.
So the question is when I do this:

`char arr[10] = "Hello";`

Do I actually have two strings in my memory?
One at `arr` until my scope ends (auto duration)
and one at the point where ever the literal was created until the program closes (static duration)

Would this be equivalent to this:

```
char* str = "Hello";
char arr[10];
memcpy(arr,str,6);
```

If this is true, then I want to make sure what happens with
`char a = 'a';`

Does this also have double allocation? I would have guessed `'a'` would be written directly to `a`

Resulting in my last question  would this be more memory efficient?

`char arr[10] =  { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'}`

Comment: I think yes. There will be two copies of the string. See this question- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38146826/returning-string-from-a-c-function

Comment: `char arr[10] =  { 'H', 'a', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'}` and `char arr[10] = "Hello";` are strictly the same thing.

Comment: @MichaelWalz thank your for clarifying that and I got the answer to the first part of the question as well. Last question is does `'a'` use additional storage besides `a`?

Comment: `char a = 'a';` is the same thing as `char a; ...; a = 'a';`, so your thoughts are correct `'a'` is simply written to `a`.